# Resample function works under Linux but not Windows

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have use below python code to deal with timeserias data, this file run well under linux system, but in widows can not run:

the featgen.py code is below:

```
import os
import sys
import cPickle as pickle
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from pprint import pprint
import csv

import talib
from talib import abstract
from talib import common
from talib import func

from featsel import Feature_Sel


class Feature_Gen():

    ###############################################################################
    def __init__(self, csv_path = './data/ZJIFMI201210-201410.csv', pkl_path = './data/data.pkl', resample_time = "10min"):
        self.csv_path = csv_path
        self.resample_time = resample_time
        self.pkl_path = os.path.join("data", "data_{}.pkl".format(resample_time))

    ###############################################################################
    def feature_gen(self):
        if os.path.exists(self.pkl_path):
            print 'read data from:', self.pkl_path
            data = pd.read_pickle(self.pkl_path)
        else:
            print 'read data from:', self.csv_path
            lines = sum(1 for _ in csv.reader(open(self.csv_path)))
            rs_num = 10000
            col_names = ['Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adjust']
            rs = pd.read_csv(
                self.csv_path,
                header = None,
                index_col = 0,
                names = col_names,
                parse_dates = {'Timestamp':['Date', 'Time']},
                # skiprows = lines-rs_num
            )
            # print rs.head(10)
            # print rs.tail(10)

            #############################################################################
            ## resample
            if self.resample_time is None:
                data = rs.ix[:, 0:5]
                # print data.shape # OHLCV
                save_pkl_path = os.path.split(self.pkl_path)[0]+'/data.pkl'
            else:
                ***tt1 = rs.Close.resample(self.resample_time, how = 'ohlc')***
                Volume = rs.Volume.resample(self.resample_time, how = 'sum')
                tt1['volume'] = Volume
                data = tt1.dropna()
                # print data.shape # ohlcv
                print 'resample_time:', self.resample_time
                save_pkl_path = os.path.split(self.pkl_path)[0]+'/data_'+self.resample_time+'.pkl'
                print save_pkl_path

            ##################################### Feature Selection #####################################
            ###################################################################### need to discuss
            '''you can switch the feature selection function here'''
            data = Feature_Sel(data).feature_sel5()

            ###############################################################################
            # data = data.dropna()
            # data = data.fillna(method="bfill")

            ###############################################################################
            with open(save_pkl_path, "wb") as fp:
                pickle.dump(data, fp)

        ###############################################################################
        # import pylab as pl
        # pl.plot(data.values[:, 3])
        # pl.savefig("./data/Close.png")

        return data


if __name__ == '__main__':

    '''First, search the *pkl file, if not exist, search the *csv file.'''
    '''Default Parameters: csv_path = './data/ZJIFMI201210-201410.csv', pkl_path = './data/data.pkl', resample_time = None'''
    data = Feature_Gen().feature_gen()
    print data
```

When run the code under windows, it returned below error:

> File "C:\Anaconda\sigming-task1-DEV\featgen.py", line 57, in
>   feature_gen
>       tt1 = rs.Close.resample(self.resample_time, how = 'ohlc')   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3032, in
>   resample
>       return sampler.resample(self).**finalize**(self)   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\resample.py", line 105,
>   in resample
>       raise TypeError('Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex') TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex
>   or PeriodIndex

Any good suggestions?

Comment: What version pandas are you running? Also can you post the output from your `df.info()` I'm assuming your df is `rs`

Comment: Pandas 0.16, yes, df is rs, it is very strange that, my code run well in my linux system, but can not run under windows

Comment: Can you confirm that the dtype is a datetime based one

Comment: Yes, it should be. If you want, i can send you my whole python code for test; the code & also the data are very small.

Comment: No I'd rather you edit your question with more information and raw input data or a link to your data, can you post what the dtype for `resample_time` is

Comment: Sorry **should** is not the same as **is** please confirm, also if it's a string why do you expect this to work when you get a TypeError?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. it is string '10min', but this code can work under Linux. Any change I must do when run this code under winows?

Comment: Can you confirm that `rs.Close` and `rs.Volume` are datetime dtypes